# Is the statement true?$|z+1|\ge|z|-1\ \forall z\in\Bbb{C}$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I have tried to prove it in the following manner-
$||z|-1|=||z|-|1||\le|z-1|\ \forall z\in\Bbb{C}$ (by Triangle inequality) 
Now, can I write $|z-1|\le|z+1|$ in $\Bbb{C}$? If yes then the proof is done.
But I can't get it. I don't know whether the statement is true. Can anybody solve it? Thanks for the assistance in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|z|=|z+1-1|\leq |z+1|+1$. Now just pull 1 on RHS to LHS.

Comment: Simple and concise(+1)!

Answer (score 0):

The triangle inequality doesn't say that $||z|-|1||\le|z-1|$. It says that $|a+b|\le|a|+|b|$ for all $a,b$.

What does it say if $a=z+1$ and $b=-1$?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with the reverse triangle inequality ($||z|-|w||\leq |z-w|$) works well with a slight adjustment.

Just note that

- $a\leq |a|$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and
- letting $w = -1$ you get immediately
  $$|z|-1 \leq ||z|-|-1||\leq |z -(-1)| = |z+1|$$